# Ajax data returning only one record

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an `jQuery ajax` code snippet that returns a record from the database, that has the same company name as the user inserted in a form.

However the code is returning only one record. Let's say i have 3 records with a company name 'A'.

The code will return only the latest record of these 3, and not all of them.

#### How can i solve this to return all the records that hold the name input by the user?

```
var key = null;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GetRecord?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY",
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
        "Where": "COMPANY='" + companies_name + "'"   
    },
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('record').each(function() {
            key = $(this).find("KEY").text();
        });

        if (key) {
            var url = "GetDisplay?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY&Where=KEY=" + key + "";
            window.open(url, "_self");
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats your server side script?Are you parsing it correctly?

Comment: try to put if statement inside the .each loop  cause while you use it after .each it will give you just the last value

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef what sort of an if statement should i put?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/m8wm3tqz/  try to uncomment the alert(key) here and comment another one .. if you alert it outside it gives you the last key .. if it inside loop it will give you each key

Comment: i agree with @Mohamed-Yousef , you have to put if statement inside function or for better check put alert inside the success function like this
alert(key) and check what value you got and compare with outer key value, it must be different.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes you're right, but how do you suggest i bypass that so i can send all the valid keys in my url? i have put the if statement insidde the .each but same result

Comment: Look... in your posted code you should use key inside the loop to get all data like I said before .. but if it keeps to output the same result so just one record data returned from xml .. It will be better to show your xml code .. or try to alert($(xml).html()) in your success function and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

try passing all the keys to the url string separated by `,`(comma) delimiter.
while processing `GetDisplay`, fetch all the records associated to the keys in the query string.

```
var key = [];
var allKeys = null;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "GetRecord?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY",
  dataType: 'xml',
  data: {
     "Where": "COMPANY='" + companies_name + "'"   
  },
  success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('record').each(function(index) {
          key [index] = $(this).find("KEY").text();
      });

     allKeys = key.join(',');
     if (key) {
        var url = "GetDisplay?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY&Where=KEY=" + allKeys + "";
        window.open(url, "_self");
     }
  },
  error: function(error) {
     alert('error');
  }
});
```

Comment: I got no records back

Comment: How are you procesing this url `GetDisplay?DB=EMP&Table=EMP_HISTORY&Where=KEY=`?